# How to split data.frame to equal columns

Tags: r

Here is sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(seq(1,10,1)))); rownames(df) <- NULL; 
colnames(df) <- letters[1:ncol(df)]
df
```

I would like to arrange the new data.frame so that it always has `6` columns, the next row (after splinting since ncol>6) would contain the next 6 column names and next row their values. The last row if ncol<6 the values are filled with empty string including the column names.

Here is desired output:

```
  a b c d e f 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6  
2 g h i j 
3 7 8 9 10
```

Another example:

```
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(seq(1,15,1)))); rownames(df) <- NULL; 
colnames(df) <- letters[1:ncol(df)]
df

  a b c d e f
1 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 g h i j k l
3 7 8 9 10 11 12
4 m n o
5 13 14 15
```

EDIT:

The way to approach it possibly is to:

```
n <- 6
ncl <- nrow(df)

s <- split(df, rep(1:ceiling(ncl/n), each=n, length.out=ncl))
s

s1 <- split(rownames(df), rep(1:ceiling(ncl/n), each=n, length.out=ncl))
s1
```

combine every second split of `s` and `s1`

```
s1[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, not so pretty, but this is an ugly question :D

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- matrix(c(names(df),rep('',6 - ncol(df)%%6)) %>% unlist, ncol=6,byrow=T) %>% as_tibble %>% rowid_to_column()
df2 <- matrix(c(df       ,rep('',6 - ncol(df)%%6)) %>% unlist, ncol=6,byrow=T) %>% as_tibble %>% rowid_to_column()
bind_rows(df1,df2) %>% arrange(rowid) %>% select(-1) %>% setNames(.[1,]) %>% slice(-1)

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#       a     b     c     d     e     f
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1     2     3     4     5     6
# 2     g     h     i     j            
# 3     7     8     9    10
```

Answer (score 1):

For the life of me I can't figure out a use-case for this... but for sake of the provided examples...

```
seq(1, ncol(df), by = 6) %>% {
    starts <- .
    ends <- c(lead(.,1,NULL)-1, ncol(df))
    base_df <- df[,starts[[1]]:ends[[1]]]
    rbind(base_df, rbind.pages(Map(function(s, e){
       d <- df[,seq(s, e)]
       data.frame(rbind(colnames(d), d)) %>% setNames(colnames(base_df)[1:length(.)])
    }, s = starts[-1], e = ends[-1]))
        )  %>% 
        mutate_all(function(x){
            ifelse(!is.na(x), x, "")
        })
}

   a  b  c  d  e  f
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  g  h  i  j  k  l
3  7  8  9 10 11 12
4  m  n  o         
5 13 14 15
```

## EDIT to coerce NA to 'empty string'

Comment: it works with the example, but not on real data. The solution is  too complicated for this task (ugly hack), which makes me think how to adapt it (fix) to the needs. Also you need `jsonlite` package to make it work plus the `rbind.pages` is not deprecated and instead use `rbind_pages`. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't give the desired output